# Android How to increase the Layout editor hint display time

Tags: android, attributes, hints, android-layout-editor

[screenshot of attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aPM8.jpg) keeping cursor on an attibute name for a while, make the contestual help to be displayed;
Problem:  it desappears to early, sometimes before Ican fully read the tip.
How is possible to increase the duration time of this kindof displays?

Thank you for help.
Claudio

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the message that appears when mouse is placed upon a widget is disappearing too fast, this is for you

I have also faced this issue, the issue is because when the mouse has reached the border of the layout, the hint starts appearing and when you move it slightly, (even if you move it mouse to center) it disappears. I think it is something to be fixed by developers. But try this for now:

a) Try not scrolling the mouse once it reaches the border of the layout.

b) Try pressing ctrl+f1 (for windows) to view the message

Hope it helps, Happy Coding

Comment: Thank you, may be your answer will help in different situation. I just added a screenshot of the attributes where  put cursor to see help and it stays too short

Comment: Unfortunately, not..pls quote my question if you think is worth.. reputation..